# Deploying Flask app on Heroku with local dependencies

Tags: python, flask, heroku

I created a Flask app that I would like to deploy on Heroku (or similar platform).  The process I've followed in the past is to creating a 'requirements.txt' file with the packages from my venv and Heroku installs them in the virtual server.  The issue I am having is that I have changed some of the code in the Flask library to get the app to work like I want.  Is there some way to load local packages?  Should I remove it from my venv/lib folder and add it to my main folder?

Thanks,
Marc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use git for that.
Please check this link.  https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/python-pip#local-file-backed-distributions

You would have to out the local library in the git repo and then update your requirements.txt file